# How to populate a whole form after ajax GET request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on ASP.NET MVC project and have an empty form rendered by MVC controller. Right after it's been rendered, I make an AJAX GET request, and receive JSON data to populate the form.

Everything works fine when I populate each individual field (please see code below), but I have a feeling that there is a better/righter way of how to populate the entire form in one shot. Please help.

In my $.get request, I tried:

```
$("#content").html(data);
```

It simply empties my form (all fields disappear).

Then I tried:

```
$("#content").val(data);
```

Here, all fields stay blank.

Anyways, here is the code that I have (please see below).

Here is my view (.cshtml file):

```html
@model ViewModels.ProductDetailsViewModel

<form asp-controller="ApiProduct" asp-action="Post" id="content">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="js-name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label">Description</label>
        <textarea asp-for="Description" rows="5" cols="40" class="form-control" id="js-description"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
      
      var id = @Model.Id;
      
        $.get("/apiproduct/get/?id=" + id, function (data) {
          
            $("#js-name").val(data.name);
            $("#js-description").val(data.description);
         
          });
      
    </script>
}
​
```

Here is my API controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var product = _repository.GetProductById(id);

        return Ok(product);
    }
```

Here is my MVC controller:

```
  public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var vm = new ProductDetailsViewModel()
        {
            Id = id;
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: why do you populate you fields with ajax and not load all the data at page load using asp.net?

Comment: I know it could be easier to fill the viewModel in the MVC controller and pass it to the view, but I'm just trying to increase performance. Besides, I know how to do that and I do NOT know how to fill form with JSON correctly.  Please correct me if I am mistaking, but I think passing raw data to the page is faster than data+html. I am fairly new to this business. @mongesh madhavan

Answer (score 0):

Apri478 ...Your API is giving you JSon result of your product and not html. 
Above this line write console.log(data) 
$("#content").html(data);

and see your response of API.

If you bind this json to form there are plenty of way.. writing custom js binding or using MVVM like angular or knockout.

try to explain more if this is not what you were expecting.

Comment: Yes, I know that I am getting JSON result and hot html. I just thought that there is some sort of built-in jquery mechanism than can map html fields with json result.

Comment: I know that angular could handle it pretty easily, I just want to build this project purely on ASP.NET MVC. I am fairly new to it, and this is my practice project. @madalin ivascu